# Does the HTML Agility Pack contain unmanaged code? If so, will I encounter problems in my application?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Does the HTML Agility Pack contain unmanaged code?  If so, will I see any problems when using unmanaged code in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the HAP is 100% managed code. It's even supported in Mono wich is a cross-platform equivalent of the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

It is available as C# source, so I don't think so. You would have to check for `extern`s, but that is about it...

Answer (score 0):

I just had a quick peek in the code as I had it handy - I couldn't find any extern's or any instances of DllImport (as of 1.4 beta 2).